# How can I randomise drawings C# Windows Form Aplication?

Tags: c#, winforms

so i got a problem and i cant find an answer yet, hope u guys can help me.
I want to create some randoms drawings for exameple a rectangle and an ellipse, but i want them to be random when i resize form. For now i can only get 1 of them or combine when i resize . Ty

```
do
{
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        while (i <= this.Width)
        {
            Desen.DrawEllipse(blue, z + 17, 25, 25, 25);
            Desen.DrawRectangle(red, z + 17, 25, 25, 25);
            break;
        }
        Desen.DrawLine(Creion_albastru, i+30, 0, i+30, 25);
        
        i += 50;
        z += 50;
    } while (i <= this.Width);
    break;
} while (j <= this.Height);
```

I can randomise with this function but then height wont be the same

```
while (i <=this.Width)
 {
   Desen.DrawRectangle(Red, z + 17, 25, 25, n.Next(50));
   Desen.DrawEllipse(Red, z + 17, 25, 25, n.Next(50));
   break;
 }
```

Comment: So what's the issue exactly? Detecting when the form has resized? Or generating random numbers? Or what? Break the problem down into the steps involved and research each one.

Comment: i want to generate random drawings when i resize form width but in the same location

Comment: P.S. I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: i dont want a code solution cuz then i will not learn how to, i just want to know how. For example i can randomise with `while (i <=this.Width)
                    {
                        Desen.DrawRectangle(Red, z + 17, 25, 25, n.Next(50));
                        Desen.DrawEllipse(Red, z + 17, 25, 25, n.Next(50));
                        break;
                    }` but then my drawings wont have the same height

Comment: If you don't know where to start, then that's what research is for. Like I said, break the problem down into the individual steps you think are needed, and learn about each one. We answer specific coding questions here. So we could help you maybe, if you've tried to build something and got stuck on a particular part of the code. We're not a tutorial site, we don't usually just give out pseudo-code algorithms, and we're not a substitute for reading documentation or other searching.

Comment: I see you've edit your comment and pasted some extra code into it. That seems more like the kind of attempt we might be able to help you with improving. Put that code and your explanation into the question itself (using the "edit" button) and that makes it into a more specific issue we can focus on.

Comment: If you want them to have the same height, then declare a variable to hold your random value: `int h = n.Next(50);`.  Now use "h" in both lines of code...

Comment: Also, your `while` should just be an `if` with the `break;` removed.

Comment: Fixed, ty for help and explication now i just need to edit my code so it can work like i wanted

Comment: _"so i got a problem and i cant find an answer yet, hope u guys can help me."_ is implied by every question posted on Stack Overflow.  There's no need to spell it out explicitly, so you are welcome to omit that kind of superfluous preamble from your question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first create procedures that create random images that you want:

```
private readonly Random rnd = new Random();

Color RandomColor => Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255));
int RandomPenSize => rnd.Next(10);
Pen RandomPen => new Pen(RandomColor, randomPenSize);

void DrawRandomRectangle(Graphics graphics, Rectangle imagePlane)
{
    // use rnd to create a Rectangle that fits inside imagePlane
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(...);
    graphics.DrawRectangle(RandomPen, rect);
}
void DrawRandomEllipse(Graphics graphics, Rectangle imagePlane)
{
    // use rnd to create a Rectangle that fits inside imagePlane
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(...);
    graphics.DrawEllipse(RandomPen, rect);
}
```

etc. Create one Draw method for every shape you want to draw. Consider also some wild random Brushes to fill the shapes.

```
enum Shape
{
    Rectangle,
    Ellipse,
    Line,
    FilledCircle,
    FilledOctagon,
    ...
}

static int MaxShapeValue {get;} = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Shape)).Length;
static Shape RandomShape => (Shape)rnd.GetNext(MaxShapeValue);
```

Procedures to Draw random shape:

```
void DrawRandomShape(Graphics graphics, Rectangle imagePlane)
{
    Shape randomShape = this.RandomShape;
    this.DrawRandomShape(randomShape, graphics, imagePlane);
}

void DrawRandomShape(Shape shape, Graphics graphics, Rectangle imagePlane)
{
    switch (shape)
    {
        case Shape.Rectangle:
            this.DrawRandomRectangle(graphics, imagePlane);
            break;
        case Shap.Ellipse:
            this.DrawRandomEllipse(graphics, imagePlane);
            break;
        case ...
    }
}
```

> I want to create some random drawings...

How do you want to show your Drawings? The easiest is to put the Drawing in an Image and display the bitmap in a PictureBox.

```
Image CreateRandomImage(int width, int height)
{
    Image image = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)
    {
        Rectangle imagePlane = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        this.DrawRandomShape(graphics, imagePlane);
    }
    return image;
}
```

Usage:

```
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
pictureBox.SizeChanged += OnPictureBoxSizeChanged;

private void OnPictureBoxSizeChanged(object sender, ...)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    Image image = this.CreateRandomImage(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
    pictureBox.Image = image;
}
```

You could also Paint directly in your control. The advantage is that you can draw the shape in any control. However I wouldn't recommend this, because this means that you would draw over other items that are in the control.

```
private void OnPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (control)sender;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height);
    DrawRandomShape(e.Graphics, rect);
}
```

Usage:

```
Control randomDrawControl = new GroupBox();   // or Label, or TextBox, or your Form
randomDrawControl.Paint += OnPaint;
```

Until now, both the PictureBox method and the OnPaint method work, even if you want this on ten different controls in your form.

The difference is, that the paint method will change the image whenever the control is to be repainted. The PictureBox method will only change when the pictureBox resizes.

If you really only want to change after resize, then my advice would be to show the image in  PictureBox. The PictureBox knows how to repaint the image if it is not changed, also after move / something covers the control / minimize (or does minimize also cause sizechanged?)

If you really have good reasons not to use a PictureBox, remember that a new image is requested, and calculate the image in OnPaint

```
bool newImageRequested = false;

void SizeChanged(object sender, ...)
{
    newImageRequested = true;
    ((Control)sender).Invalidate(); // this will cause a repaint of the complete control
}

private void OnPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.newImageRequsted)
    {
        ... // show a new image; see above
        this.newImageRequested = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty for this example , i will try it